# Open Push notification in web standalone on android

Tags: html, push-notification, manifest, service-worker, web-push

i have a service worker for the gcm push notifications on my website
the manifest is done so for mobile the website becomes a standalone web app

now my question when the webapp is open everything works fine.
but when the webapp is closed i receive a normal push notification that opens google chrome on click. instead of my standalone webapp.

how to get it to open the standalone webapp instead?

PS not talking about downloadable app but web-app

Comment: Are you talking about the fullscreen mode you get from webapp added to the home screen? You wish those notifications would keep this fullscreen effect right?

Comment: it is not fullscreen but indeed without browser url bar.

Now it opens a new chrome browser and displays the website, while i want IF someone already added the website as a standalone to his desktop that it open there.

Comment: david were you able to fins a fix, the crbug.com/541711 shows its been fixed , yet i am getting the same browser mode on notification click.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem in Chrome. There is a [bug open for it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541711) (crbug.com/541711) so I don't think there is a way to do what you want right now.